# EC2 AMI won't boot after edit

Tags: amazon-ec2

I did something stupid, I got a new laptop and copied everything over to the new one, then wiped the old one clean. Then I realized that I forgot to copy the private key out of .ssh that I use to connect to my AWS EBS backed instance.

So I can't log in to my custom AMI. So I created a new Volume from the Snapshot of the AMI, then started up a public instance and attached the Volume to it, edit the sshd_config to allow for password log in. Unmounted the volume, detached it, made a snapshot of it, then made a new AMI from the snapshot.

The new AMI launches, but never passes the Status Checks and is not reachable.

What am I doing wrong? Or alternatively how can I fix my problem?

**Edit**: Adding some of the console output

```
Linux version 2.6.16-xenU (builder@xenbat.amazonsa) (gcc version 4.0.1 20050727 (Red Hat 4.0.1-5)) #1 SMP Mon May 28 03:41:49 SAST 2007
BIOS-provided physical RAM map:
 Xen: 0000000000000000 - 000000006a400000 (usable)
980MB HIGHMEM available.
727MB LOWMEM available.
NX (Execute Disable) protection: active
IRQ lockup detection disabled
RAMDISK driver initialized: 16 RAM disks of 4096K size 1024 blocksize
NET: Registered protocol family 2

Registering block device major 8
XENBUS: Timeout connecting to devices!

Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(8,0)
```

Comment: Check the [console output](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSEC2/latest/CommandLineReference/ApiReference-cmd-GetConsoleOutput.html).

Comment: Thanks for that suggestions. Last line is Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(8,0)

Comment: What you did sounds fine, but for some reason the root filesystem can't be mounted.

Comment: The first thing I ever do with an Amazon instance is add my own SSH keys to it. It helps a lot with preventing this sort of thing from happening, since I have backups of my SSH keys. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you register the new AMI make sure you specify the correct AKI (kernel), the same as the previous AMI.

Comment: I just got it running, turns out I needed to specify the kernel like you said, and whoever made the original AMI that I built on must have used the command line because they specified the root name as /dev/sda1 and the root block as /dev/sda. If your using the console there is no way to make them different. Like the kernel they need to match the original AMI.